How can I attach a 2-1/2” hose to my dust collector?

I can just barely get the end of the hose onto the intake. How do i get it further down? Some sort of lubricant? Heat?

You're a longtime SEer, presumably you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Share what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.

maybe try some baby powder

What have you tried and how has it worked?

According to the makers website:

Designed with industry-standard vacuums in mind, the Quick Click Separator connects easily to a wide range of wet-dry vacuums, including popular brands like Rigid, Shop Vac, Vacmaster, and DeWalt. The 2.375” inlet accommodates male hoses, while the exterior fits popular 2.5” dust collection hoses commonly used in both home and commercial workshops, eliminating the need for adapters or duct tape.
www.centecsystems.com

So the inlet is designed to receive a 2.5" connection. The 2.5" hose will not slide over the inlet.

Diagram is contained in the slide show for this product
If you have a length of 2.5" pipe you should be able to slide your hose onto it and then slide the pipe into the dust collector.

Thanks for the perspective. I've ordered two adaptors that mate a 2-1/2" hose to a 2-1/4" ID inlet. They're supposed to arrive tomorrow; I'll follow up with a note about how that works.
